# Принимать данные на вебсервере по мере их поступления на python

Tags: python, aiohttp

Необходимо принимать и обрабатывать бинарные данные поступающие на http server не дожидаясь окончания запроса. На nodejs этот функционал доступен из коробки, в python смотрел aiohttp и пр. но нужного мне функционала не нашел, неужели придется через tcp сервер реализовывать?

Comment: Кажется, плохо смотрели https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.BaseRequest.content

Comment: Именно то что было необходимо, спасибо.